# Can't get Windows to boot after editing partitions

Tags: bootcamp, startup, partition

When I attempt to boot Windows I get the error 0xc000000e. This happened after I made a partition in Windows and then deleted it in Mac OS.

Here's my current set up. Is it possible to repair it using GDisk? I've added a description of each partition to the list.

```
    *** Report for internal hard disk ***

    Current GPT partition table:
     #      Start LBA      End LBA  Type
     1             40       409639  EFI System   (FAT)
     2         409640    166400863  Mac OS X HFS+   (Mac OS)
     3      167731200    169062399  Mac OS X HFS+   (Recovery)
     4      169062400    215558143  Basic Data   (New Partition)
     5      215558144    368127999  Basic Data   (Bootcamp)
     6      368128000    369049599  Unknown   (Don't know how this got here)
     7      369049600    490231807  Basic Data   (Files)

    Current MBR partition table:
 # A    Start LBA      End LBA  Type
 1              1       409639  ee  EFI Protective
 2 *       409640    166400863  af  Mac OS X HFS+
 3      169062400    215558143  07  NTFS/HPFS
 4 *    215558144    368127999  07  NTFS/HPFS

MBR contents:
 Boot Code: None

Partition at LBA 40:
 Boot Code: Windows BOOTMGR (Vista)
 File System: FAT32
 Listed in GPT as partition 1, type EFI System (FAT)

Partition at LBA 409640:
 Boot Code: None
 File System: HFS Extended (HFS+)
 Listed in GPT as partition 2, type Mac OS X HFS+
 Listed in MBR as partition 2, type af  Mac OS X HFS+, active

Partition at LBA 167731200:
 Boot Code: None
 File System: HFS Extended (HFS+)
 Listed in GPT as partition 3, type Mac OS X HFS+

Partition at LBA 169062400:
 Boot Code: None (Non-system disk message)
 File System: FAT32
 Listed in GPT as partition 4, type Basic Data
 Listed in MBR as partition 3, type 07  NTFS/HPFS

Partition at LBA 215558144:
 Boot Code: Windows BOOTMGR (Vista)
 File System: NTFS
 Listed in GPT as partition 5, type Basic Data
 Listed in MBR as partition 4, type 07  NTFS/HPFS, active

Partition at LBA 368128000:
 Boot Code: Windows BOOTMGR (Vista)
 File System: NTFS
 Listed in GPT as partition 6, type Unknown

Partition at LBA 369049600:
 Boot Code: Windows BOOTMGR (Vista)
 File System: NTFS
 Listed in GPT as partition 7, type Basic Data
```

I've tried to recreate the deleted partition (4) and added it to the MBR block. It still doesn't work.

Comment: Golden Rule - never let Windows touch the partitions, it simply doesn't understand how they are constructed.

Comment: Last time I did it, it worked fine.

Comment: Windows is unaware that the volume it thinks is MBR is actually GUID underneath. Boot Camp 'fools' it into thinking it's MBR.

Comment: Great, so how do I fix this mess?

Comment: I'd hope @klanomath reads this thread - he's bona fide wizard at this stuff - or search some of his answers in Ask Different .. http://apple.stackexchange.com/users/93229/klanomath

Comment: I get the impression that I could set the MBR to any combination and wouldn't work.